# Updating an asyncronous polling library to modern async paradigm

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, com, task-parallel-library

I have this (working) bare-bones implementation of an asynchronous polling callback loop:

```
public void Start(ICallback callback)
{
    if (Callback != null)
        Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("STARTING");
    Callback = callback;
    cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    this.task = Task.Run(() => TaskLoop(), cancellation.Token);
    Console.WriteLine("STARTED");
}

public void Stop()
{
    if (Callback == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ALREADY stopped");
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("STOPPING");
    cancellation.Cancel();
    try
    {
        task.Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        cancellation.Dispose();
        cancellation = null;
        Callback = null;
        task = null;
        Console.WriteLine("STOPPED");
    }
}

private void TaskLoop()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Starting iteration... {0}", i);
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //just for testing
            Callback.SendMessage($"Iteration {i} at {System.DateTime.Now}");
        }).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("...Ending iteration {0}", i++);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("CANCELLED");
}
```

It's actually called from unmanaged C++ via COM, so this is a library project (and the callback is a COM-marshalled object) hence wanting to test the design first.

I'm switching to using the `async` paradigm and wonder if it should be as simple as sprinkling some `async` dust on my method declarations and swapping `Wait()` calls for `await`? Obviously `Thread.Sleep` would be changed for `Task.Delay`.

I am fairly sure COM will dedicate a thread to this object for marshaling purposes and unmanaged C++ doesn't know about the .Net async model, so are there any gotchas/pitfalls to watch out for?

This is an updated version I'm testing but, like Resource management, multithreading is an area your code can seem to work perfectly but is actually quite badly broken so I'd appreciate thoughts:

```
public void Start(ICallback callback)
{
    if (Callback != null)
        Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("STARTING");
    Callback = callback;
    cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    this.task = TaskLoopAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("STARTED");
}

public async void Stop()
{
    if (Callback == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ALREADY stopped");
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("STOPPING");
    cancellation.Cancel();
    try
    {
        await task;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        cancellation.Dispose();
        cancellation = null;
        Callback = null;
        task = null;
        Console.WriteLine("STOPPED");
    }
}

private async void TaskLoopAsync()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Starting iteration... {0}", i);
        Callback.SendMessage($"Iteration {i} at {System.DateTime.Now}");
        Console.WriteLine("...Ending iteration {0}", i++);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("CANCELLED");
}
```

Comment: There is no need to "sleep / delay" and spawn a new task in `TaskLoop()`.  You can just call directly `SendMessage()`.

Comment: @Nick yeah I am wondering why I added this too. I think it was during some problems I was trying to diagnose and it never got removed after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unmanaged C++ doesn't know about the .Net async model, so are there any gotchas/pitfulls to watch out for?

Just that one. It's fine to apply `async`/`await` to your internal code (e.g., `TaskLoop`), but you can't let it extend out to the COM boundary. So `Start` and `Stop` cannot be made `async`.

Comment: Hmm. But if I change `Stop` to `await Task` instead of `Task.Wait` surely I _must_ label it `async`? I've actually tested these changes and it _seems_ to work but multithreaded code is easy to get "working with hidden bugs" :)

Comment: No, that's what you want to avoid. Don't use `async void`. Keep `Stop` synchronous.

Comment: But, how? Sacrifice a bit of perfromance and use `Wait`? And what is wrong given it (appears to) work - can you go into any more detail?

Comment: It essentially uses `Wait` already, and it should continue to do so. The [problem with `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) is that it doesn't wait. So the stop hasn't completed by the time `Stop` returns, and there's no way for the COM object to detect that.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to async introduced a bug in your code. The problem is with the `async void Stop` method. It is called from inside the `Start` method, and since there is no way to `await` an [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) method, both methods are executing concurrently for a while. So it is a matter of luck which of the two commands below will be executed first:

```
this.task = TaskLoopAsync(); // in Start method

task = null; // in Stop method
```

Other points of interest:

1. The `CancellationTokenSource` is not used the way it is intended. This class is more than a glorified `volatile bool`. It also allows to cancel asynchronous operations an any time by registering callbacks. For example you can cancel the asynchronous [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) immediately by passing the token through its second optional argument:

```
await Task.Delay(1000, cancellation.Token);
```

Then you must be prepared to handle the `OperationCanceledException` that will be thrown when the token is canceled. This is the standard way of communicating [cancellation in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads), by throwing this exception from the one end and capturing it from the other.

2. You can achieve more consistent intervals between calling the `Callback.SendMessage` method, by creating the `Task.Delay` task before calling the method, and awaiting it afterwards.